# converting a text in a dictionary

Tags: python

i have a text file like this and i am converting the text file into a dictionary. making one of the values the key and the rest the values within the key.

```
0.8, 3.5, jerry, 5.5, 0, 4, 78
0.9, 2, amy, 6.2, 4, 4, 
1.0, 4, alan, 7.8, 9, 90
```

and this is what i have cuz one of the student is missing a grade on purpose.

```
  openData = open("students.txt", 'r')

  myDic = dict()

  for col in openData:
      line = col.strip().split(",")
      q1 = line[0]
      q2 = line[1]
      name = line[3]  
      mag = line[4]
      grade = line[6]
      myDic[name] = q1, q2, mag, grade

   print(myDic)
```

my problem is when i try to run it,the output keeps saying that grade = line[6]
is out of range.
can someone help? Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with the line that's missing a grade?

Comment: You can test `len(line)` to find out how many fields are in the line, and do something different when it's less than 7.

Comment: @Barmar i want it just leave it empty when it converted to dictionary beacause some lines are shorter than others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of `line` before trying to use `line[6]`

```
for col in openData:
    line = col.strip().split(",")
    q1 = line[0]
    q2 = line[1]
    name = line[3]  
    mag = line[4]
    if len(line) >= 5:
        grade = line[6]
    else:
        grade = ''
    myDic[name] = q1, q2, mag, grade
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you place a comma after the 90 it should work fine.

```
1.0, 4, alan, 7.8, 9, 90,
```

The problem is when you split on commas you only have 6 items in the last row.

Comment: will try that. i thought it shouldnt matter if the lines are not equal? probably leave it blank when it converted to dictionary

Comment: By doing this, it will replace the empty space after the 90 with an empty string ''. How you handle missing grades is up to you, but just be aware that it will look like an empty string instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pad the end of the line:

```
myDic = dict()

for col in openData:
    line = (col + ','*6).strip().split(',')
    q1, q2, name, mag, grade = [line[i] for i in (0, 1, 2, 3, 6)]
    myDic[name] = q1, q2, mag, grade

print(myDic)
```

The `','*6` part adds 6 commas and thereby guarantees 7 fields available, substituting as many blanks as required.

This can compensate for missing data at the *end* of a line in the data file, but not in the middle. For that you probably need to clean up the source data, presumably adding commas wherever a field is blank.

Comment: Thank you. with this line of code. when i run it it includes the \n in the dictionary which normally a strip() should fix it but its not. how do i go about removing the \n at the end